# this.apply method with this as parameter

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

On Douglas Crockford's book The Good Parts, he implements the array push method on this way:

```
Array.prototype.push = function ( ) {
  this.splice.apply(
    this,
    [ this.length, 0 ].
      concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments))
  );
  return this.length;
};
```

Dont get it how works this.*method_name*.apply with itself (*this*) as parameter, in the code corresponds to `this.splice.apply`; if I use `Array.prototype.splice.apply` I don't get the correct result.

Hope somebody may explain me which is the difference here between `this.splice.apply(this, parameters)` and `Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, parameters)`

Comment: Please, format the code in your question.

Comment: There should be no difference. I can't reproduce the "*I don't get the correct result*" part.

Comment: As has been pointed out, there should be no difference between the two cases. So, show the full code that you say doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: `this.splice.apply` and `Array.prototype.splice` are the same exact function. The "only" difference is the context in which the function is used. `this.splice` uses the instance of your array as the value for `this` and `Array.prototype.splice` uses `Array.prototype` as the value for `this` which is why you need to invoke it with `.apply` in the latter case. This way, you're telling the function what to use as `this` when it's run.

the ugly truth: inside the function definition `this` does not refer to the object `Array.prototype`, but instead `this` refers to the object (in this case an array) which is an *instance* of `Array`. Because the object is an instance of `Array`, means that it inherits all properties defined on `Array.prototype`. `Array.prototype.slice` is defined on `Array.prototype` and so it's an instance method of your object, therefore you can invoke it using `this.slice`. When you call slice in this manner, `this` refers to your object, which again is an array. When you refer to slice with `Array.prototype.slice` then `this` refers to `Array.prototype` in this context, which is why you need to invoke it with `.apply(arguments)` which says "run this function and use this=arguments".

Comment: Indeed they are the same, I don't know why I was getting a different result.