# This.apply method with this

Tags: javascript

From

> Douglas Crockford javascript the good parts

Implementation of push

```
Array.method('push', function () {
    this.splice.apply(
      this,
      [this.lenght, 0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arquments));
   return this.length;
});
```

Lets analyze this with following example: I have array of 10 elements and want to add next element of value 11.

```
Array.method('push', function () {
    this.splice.apply(
      this,
      [10, 0].concat([11]);
   return this.length;
});
```

that gives me

```
Array.method('push', function () {
       this.splice.apply(this,[10, 0, 11]);
       return this.length;
    });
```

So I understand this will do this: MyInitialArray.splice(10,0,11) which will just find element at 10 position, remove nothing and add element of value 11 next to it right ?

So my main question, why there has to be construction with double this

like: this.splice.apply(this, ... ??

Simillar question was asked here but there is no answer for my question about double `this.splice.apply(this`

[this.apply method with this as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768810/this-apply-method-with-this-as-parameter)

Other words:

If I call *this.splice*, *splice* will execute with *this* allready, so why there is need to pass the same *this* with *apply* ?

Comment: Since you asked [this earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545772/this-applay-this)(now deleted) and was closed as a duplicate of the question you're now linking to, can you explain _why_ you think your question isn't answered in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768810/this-apply-method-with-this-as-parameter)?

Comment: There's no real "need" for double `this` here. It could have been `[].splice.apply(this` but that wouldn't make it better.

Comment: @JamesThorpe becase this is no answer for my questin in possible duplicate

Comment: @kosnkov: Yes, there is -- the accepted answer answers your question. Perhaps you could cite that answer and say what about it you don't understand.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was not able to find answer for my question: If I call this.splice, splice will execute with this allready, so why there is need to pass the same this with apply ?

Comment: @kosnkov: *That's* what should be in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my main question, why there has to be construction with double this

Fundamentally, because it wants to call `splice` providing the arguments as an array, rather than as discrete arguments.

`splice` expects discrete arguments, e.g.:

```
array.splice(1, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

...which means "at index 1, delete 0 entries, then add entries 'a', 'b', and 'c'."

But that code wants to call `splice` with the array `[10, 0, 11]` **as though** we'd done this:

```
this.splice(10, 0, 11);
```

We can't just do

```
this.splice([10, 0, 11]); // <== Doesn't work
```

...because that's just passing an array for the first argument, which `splice` wouldn't understand.

To spread out the array into discrete arguments, in ES5 and earlier, we have to use `Function#apply`: It calls the function you call `apply` on, accepting the arguments to give it as an array, and calls that function with those array entries *as discrete arguments*.

In order to use `Function#apply`, we need a value to give it as its first argument, which is what `this` should be during the call. So that's why the second `this` is there.

The first `this` (e.g., `this.splice`) is just there so we get the `splice` function. That line could also be:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(this, [10, 0, 11]);
// or (can't say I like this one):
[].slice.apply(this, [10, 0, 11]);
```

Re your comment:

> If I call `this.splice`, `splice` will execute with `this` allready, so why there is need to pass the same `this` with apply ?

That code isn't directly calling `this.splice`, it's calling `this.splice.apply`. `apply`'s first argument is what to use as `this` when calling the original function (`this.splice`).

---

In ES2015 (ES6), this would be done with the spread operator instead:

```
this.splice(...[10, 0, 11]);
```

The spread operator spreads the entries of the array out into discrete arguments.

Comment: Are you sure that in this example this.slice is the same what [].slice ? I thought that this is the actual array on which push was executed. So for me is more like myArray.slice([10, 0, 11]) ok this wodun't work so myArray.slice.apply(this,[10, 0, 1]) and this will be converted to myArray.slice(10, 0, 1) and with your example we would end up with [].slice(10,0,1) unless it doesn matter becease slice.apply(this, [10,0,1]) will not only transfer array into arquments but also run slice on this.

Comment: @kosnkov: It's the way the prototype chain works. The expression `this.splice` looks at the object `this` references for a `splice` property and doesn't find one; so it looks at that object's *prototype*, which is the object `Array.prototype` also points to. That object *does* have `splice`, so that's the `splice` that is used. So `this.splice`, `[].splice`, and `Array.prototype.slice` are all the same function. If we were calling it directly, it would matter (to `this` within the call) how we looked it up, but since we're using `apply` and specifying `this` explicitly, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it, now its much clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't just do

```
this.splice(this.lenght, 0, someArgument)
```

is that `push` takes a variable number of arguments, it's *variadic*. You can for example do

```
someArray.push("a", "b", "c");
```

So to emulate it, you need to pass an array, that's the purpose of `apply`. And the first `this` is just to obtain the `splice` function, it could have been

```
[].splice.apply(this, ...
```

or

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, ...
```

or

```
var spliceFunction = Array.prototype.splice;
spliceFunction.apply(this, ...
```

Comment: but my questin is what does "this.splice.apply(this" so if you have contex why is the reason to apply the same again

Comment: Assuming you've read the documentation of `apply` I don't understand what you're missing here. I'll delete this answer. EDIT: unless the edit makes it clear for you

Comment: so in this context Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, ... is the same what this.splice.apply(this ?

Comment: yes, `this.splice.apply(this` is equivalent to `Array.prototype.splice.apply(this`.